# How do I add the SonarQube Analysis Report in the build email sent from VSTS CI/CD?

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops, sonarqube-scan, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, sonarqube5.1

I am using SendGrid to send post deployment emails to the development team. Is there a way I can add the sonarqube analysis report/results to the email? Can I integrate the dashboard with my email? Any suggestions will help! Thanks!

Comment: Are you using SonarQube 5.1? Then you should plan for a major update.

Comment: i am using SonarQube 5.6.6

Comment: @vigneshsrinivasan is it ok for you to deal with related information and then send the handled information from Publish Analysis Result task via email?

Comment: How do you use SendGrid to send post deployment email? Use WebHook?

Comment: Hi Eddie..i am using SendGrid task in VSTS with SendGrid API created on Azure...we get 25000 free emails per month

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to achieve this automatically by default.

The workaround would be adding one more task like Powershell Script task to read the Analysis report/result and then pass the information to SendGrid task.